# Windows Azure Nodejs Publish Socket.io Path Error

Tags: windows, node.js, azure, socket.io, publish

Publish return the error below:

Copying file from

> .\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-parser\node_modules\base64-arraybuffer\lib\base64-arraybuffer.js

to

> obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-parser\node_modules\base64-arraybuffer\lib\base64-arraybuffer.js

failed. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.